# Can I join Maqetta and Aptana together? Is it Useful?

Tags: javascript, web, aptana, maqetta

I'm a newbie in Javascript Programming. (But I should be an expert. =_+')
 (and newbie in English Language also. ^^;)

Nowadays, I got the assignment that I should make the company standard framework for web programmers.

From my search results,
 I think...
 Maqetta is suitable for UI Design Draft, and...
 Aptana is suitable for JavaScript Programming.
 (It's just my thought.)

and I'm considering jQuery+jQueryUI+a... as Library Bases.

So, I'll set the standard IDE like this form : Eclipse + Maqetta Plugin + Aptana Plugin + jQuery(+a) Libraries..
for my Web Programmers.
 and Rough steps for programming are
1. UI Designing using Maqetta...
2. Script Coding using Aptana...

Though I'm a beginner for JavaScript but I have the duty on my Web Programmers,
 I wanna ask for comments about this set-up.
 Is it possible?
 Is it Not-Bad?
 Is it Useful?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Jon Ferraiolo answers on maqetta-users:

> The best way I can think of to use Maqetta and Aptana together would be to download Maqetta to run locally (http://maqetta.org/downloads/) and run it locally, which will cause Maqetta to save the HTML/CSS/JS file it creates on your local file system.Then you could open any of those files using Aptana for source editing.
>
> The ZIP file contains a README file inside with instructions.
>
> When you install Maqetta locally into *installfolder*, and run Maqetta from a browser for the first time, it will create a *installfolder*/maqetta/users/. You should see a single folder "a/". That's where Maqetta saves the files you create. You should be able to open those files in Aptana for source editing. Note that if you create multiple projects (via the New Project command), each new project will get its own folder (e.g., "b/", "c/", etc). Unfortunately, there is no easy way to tell which of these folders map to which project (except visual inspection).